# Can't stay connected to Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless, 12.04

Just upgraded to 12.04 this morning and all of a sudden it won't stay connected to my home wi-fi. It connects, and then about 15 seconds later it disconnects and asks to enter the password again.

However, it connects to my phone's hotspot. I have two phones, a BlackBerry Bold and a Galaxy Nexus and when i set either one of them to hotspot, my computer will connect and it stays connected, but it will not stay connected to my home wifi.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, wireless network would ask for a password to authenticate, then connect and after a couple of seconds it would disconnect again. This process would repeat itself over and over. Even with entering the password directly at the wireless security tab as described here, it would still pop-up with the password dialog box & sometimes connect, but still keep on disconnecting.

This is what I did to solve the problem - it's a workaround, but hopefully later updates will fix this issue.

1. Establish a connection to your wireless connection
2. Click on the network icon at the top right-hand of your screen
3. Select 'Edit Connections' at the bottom
4. Select the 'Wireless' tab
5. Select your network & hit 'Edit'
6. Select the 'IPv6 Settings' tab
7. Where it says 'Method: Automatic' make it 'Ignore'

That "solved" the problem for me, of course it potentially creates other issues if you need IPv6 on your wireless connection, and hopefully that gets resolved later with updates from Ubuntu or upstream.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've probably already done all of these, but I personally would restart my modem/router, first (unplug power source. Wait 45 seconds, plug back in). If that doesn't help, I'd reboot my computer. If there's still no joy, I'd look into the settings of your wifi modem/router.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem.  I just upgraded to 12.04 LTS, and then the wireless router asked for the key as soon as I powered up.  I put in the correct key, it accepted the key and said connection established, then I had from 15 to 30 seconds of normal connectivity until the network disconnected and asked for the key again.

I restarted everything with no change in its behavior.

I think I have the solution.

- Go up to the top right corner and click on the settings icon.
- Select network.
- Select wireless.
- Pull down the network name box and select your network SSID.
- Click on options.
- Click on the wireless security tab.
- Enter your network key, then click save.

After doing this, I have stayed connected for the last half hour with no problems.  If I run into anything else to add, I'll post it.